# torch.nn.functional.interpolate: difference between "linear" and "bilinear"?

Tags: python, pytorch, interpolation, image-resizing

In [torch.nn.functional.interpolate](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.interpolate.html?highlight=interpolate#torch.nn.functional.interpolate) what's the difference between the modes `linear` and `bilinear`?

To me, these are usually synonyms with regards to image resizing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pytorch is explicitly differentiating between 1d interpolation (`linear`) and 2d interpolation (`bilinear`).

They differ in the the dimensionality of the `input` argument they are allowed to work on ( [see here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/07e9f86a4bb0116d61724a2b89866fe2f438ce0f/torch/nn/functional.py#L3869-L3897) ). Specifically, `linear` works on 3D inputs and `bilinear` works on 4D inputs because the first two dimensions (mini-batch x channels) are understood not to be interpolated.

Comment: Is it possible to specify the dimension(s) along which we want to interpolate?